# How do I trigger all related events in GeckoFx?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, geckofx

I am using GeckoFx60 as a web browser component in my .NET Framework project. The browser loads a website and fills out a form on a button click.

However, the form needs to run specific JavaScript events in order to become valid. How do I change the value of a GeckoInputElement and automatically raise the needed event?

Here is my current code:

```
var collection = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

foreach (GeckoElement element in collection)
{
    switch (element)
    {
        case GeckoInputElement textbox when textbox.Id == "receiverAddressFirstname":
            textbox.Value = kundenDaten["shipping_firstname"].ToString(); // Events need to be raised here!
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What needs to happen, when, and why?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/52159094/8291949